# Add XMP Metadata to JPEG in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, metadata, jpeg, xmp

I have existing jpg photos with aspect ratio 2:1 that do not contain any XMP Metadata.  Using C#, I would like to add xmp metadata similar to what is shown below to my jpg photos. The intent is that these photos will be uploaded to Facebook and be able to be recognized as a 360 photo.

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:GPano="http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/panorama/">
<GPano:UsePanoramaViewer>True</GPano:UsePanoramaViewer>
<GPano:CaptureSoftware>Photo Sphere</GPano:CaptureSoftware>
<GPano:StitchingSoftware>Photo Sphere</GPano:StitchingSoftware>
<GPano:ProjectionType>equirectangular</GPano:ProjectionType>
<GPano:PoseHeadingDegrees>350.0</GPano:PoseHeadingDegrees>
<GPano:InitialViewHeadingDegrees>90.0</GPano:InitialViewHeadingDegrees>
<GPano:InitialViewPitchDegrees>0.0</GPano:InitialViewPitchDegrees>
<GPano:InitialViewRollDegrees>0.0</GPano:InitialViewRollDegrees>
<GPano:InitialHorizontalFOVDegrees>75.0</GPano:InitialHorizontalFOVDegrees>
<GPano:CroppedAreaLeftPixels>0</GPano:CroppedAreaLeftPixels>
<GPano:CroppedAreaTopPixels>0</GPano:CroppedAreaTopPixels>
<GPano:CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels>4000</GPano:CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels>
<GPano:CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels>2000</GPano:CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels>
<GPano:FullPanoWidthPixels>4000</GPano:FullPanoWidthPixels>
<GPano:FullPanoHeightPixels>2000</GPano:FullPanoHeightPixels>
<GPano:FirstPhotoDate>2012-11-07T21:03:13.465Z</GPano:FirstPhotoDate>
<GPano:LastPhotoDate>2012-11-07T21:04:10.897Z</GPano:LastPhotoDate>
<GPano:SourcePhotosCount>50</GPano:SourcePhotosCount>
<GPano:ExposureLockUsed>False</GPano:ExposureLockUsed>
</rdf:Description>
```

My existing solution simply sets the camera make and model to "RICOH" and "RICOH THETA S" respectively in the EXIF metadata.  Although this works, I would like to use xmp metadata so I can specify specific fields for Facebook to recognize such as InitialViewHeadingDegrees.

## Current Solution

```
public static Stream addThetaTags(Stream stream)
    {
        // Create image
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);

        PropertyItem make = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
        make.Id = 0x010F;
        make.Len = 22;
        make.Type = 2;
        make.Value = new Byte[] { 82, 73, 67, 79, 72, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 0 };

        PropertyItem model = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
        model.Id = 0x0110;
        model.Len = 64;
        model.Type = 2;
        model.Value = new Byte[] { 82, 73, 67, 79, 72, 32, 84, 72, 69, 84, 65, 32, 83, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 0 };

        // Set make property to RICOH
        image.SetPropertyItem(make);

        //set model property to RICOH THETA S
        image.SetPropertyItem(model);

        //save image as stream
        Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // If you're going to read from the stream, you may need to reset the position to the start
        ms.Position = 0;
        return ms;
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any answer for this?

Comment: No I have not figured this out